# Could a language have only five verb conjugations?

Tags: language, alternate-reality, conlang

As far as I understand with my rocky, basic understanding of linguistics (and my less-basic experience with learning languages), most languages have six verb conjugations:

- **I**
- **You singular**
- **He/She/It**
- **We**
- **You plural**
- **They**

Obviously, verbs are more complicated than just these conjugations (there's tenses, perfective and imperfective aspects, verbs of motion, imperative, and gerunds), but for now, just focus on conjugation. Is there some way to collapse these six conjugations into five? On a related note, are there natural earth languages with five conjugations?

Also, I need exactly five conjugations. The two conjugations (sort of) of English won't work--it needs to be exactly five conjugations.

So, yeah. Are there normal languages with only five conjugations? If there aren't, what would be the most realistic way to make one?

Comment: There's a home specially for this sort of thing now: https://conlang.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this question is better suited for https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: (1) You are using the word "conjugation" is an extremely non-standard sense. Those six "things" are called "persons", namely 1st singular, 2nd singular, 3rd singular, 1st plural (sometimes called 4th), etc. (2) Romanian verbs most usually have five forms in the indicative present active; the trick is to know *which* five -- it depends on the conjugation (in the standard sense). In the 1st conjugation 3 singular is the same as 3 plural; in the 2nd, 3rd and 4th conjugations 1 singular is the same as 3 plural. Etc.

Comment: Mandarin does not change the verb, but puts modifiers around them. As wo qu, I go, wo men qu, we go, ni men qu le, you (plural) went, ta men jiang qu, they will go. Always qu for go. And the same modifiers for all verbs. So lai is come or arrive. You just put lai in for qu, and you have new correct sentences. Wo lai, I come, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The answer is in your question.**

The need to differentiate between you singular and plural shows that English only has 5 conjugations. The issue is the mentality behind whether or not there is a difference. In spoken language we usually add additional words to clarify or use tone of voice or even hand gestures to do so.

That said, if a society does not differentiate between two forms as a mentality, there would be no need to even consider it. If you use a collective mentality as an example, maybe there is no difference between singular and plural, therefore all tenses would be along the lines of we/us, you plural, and they. That would be a bit excessive though as it reduces conjugation to 3 instead of 5.

If you are creating a language then you really just have to pick two conjugations that are similar and use the same for both. You could possibly get rid of first person singular if as a societal norm individuals always refer to themselves in third person, therefore there is no singular tense.

Bottom line is you have options. Languages grow organically and can take basically whatever form we want. You really just need a viable reason they developed that way.

Answer (score 2):

Combine the third persons singular and plural. Instead of "he / she / it / they", just have the language use "they". Of course, SE probably has something to say on the matter of pronouns...

Comment: Moreover, English is a natural example of a similar evolution; in modern Modern English there is no distinction between the second person singular and the second person plural. Nowadays no English verb or pronoun distinguishes between them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and there is/are.

Take eg. Spanish as spoken in Latin America: the "you plural" is folded into the "they" conjugation, leaving five forms.

Comment: You really really shouldn't perpetuate the aberrant use of the word "conjugation" used in the question simply because the querent did not know any better. What you wanted to say is that in Latin American Spanish the 2nd person plural has the same form as the 3rd person plural.